# Aliasing in Pulse Wave Doppler/Radar

Tags: waves, acoustics, radar

There are many pictures on the Internet showing sampling of the output wave and then showing the phenomenon of aliasing, e.g.:

[image]

But on the other hand, I find information that in the pulse (Pulse Wave Doppler in Ultrasound or Radar), and the next pulse (next sample) is released when the previous one returns. How is it possible that there can be several samples in one cycle and the pulse (sample) itself consists of several cycles?

Comment: You are being confused by the confusing use of the word "sample". Indeed, in the matched filter one usually takes the peak amplitude and its phase as "the" sample, this was the old days. One could take more "digital" samples per pulse and numerically interpolate to find the "true" peak, these are the newer days. From peak sample to peak sample the elapsed time is the pulse repetition interval. The ratio of the peak to peak *phase shift* to PRI is the Doppler shift.